# Disable onClick event on a FluentUI React component

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript, fluent-ui, fluentui-react

I have a Card Fluent UI component defined like this

```
    <Card className={mergeClasses(styles.card, className)} onClick={() => onClicked(id)} >
        <CardContent {...props} />
        <CardBottom {...props} onSave={() => onSaved(id)} />
    </Card >
```

The `onClick()` method needs to be defined at the `Card` component level, but I don't want to run this onClick event when clicking on the `CardBottom` area since that contains other button that is executing its own event (`onSaved`).

Is there a way I can skip running the `onClick` event when the click happens in the `CardBottom` component?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can stop the propagation of the event in *CardBottom* component's event handler.

**Change:**

```
<CardBottom {...props} onSave={() => onSaved(id)} />
```

**To:**

```
<CardBottom
  {...props}
  onSave={(event) => {
    event.stopPropagation(); //stop the propagation
    onSaved(id);
  }}
/>
```

Comment: Worked like a charm! Marking as valid answer